# VSCode clangd won't suggest types in STL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

Clangd doesn't suggest while I'm typing like 'shared' (I want `std::shared_ptr` suggested), unless the corresponding headers are included.
But in another project of mine, clangd works well.
[image: screen shot of the broken one]

[image: screen shot of the good one]

I notice that only `type`s miss in the broken one, `function`s in STL are suggested as expected.
Configurations of clangd in this two projects are exactly the same.

[image: configuration of the broken one]

[image: configuration of the good one]

What I expect:
While I'm typing like `std::abc`, clangd should suggest all possibilities in `std` matching `abc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the behaviour varies from project to project is that the completions being offered depends on the symbols being present in the project's index, which will happen if **any file** in the project (not necessarily the one you're editing) includes the header defining them.

In clangd 15, a feature was added to get clangd to pro-actively index all the standard library headers (as if an invisible file in the project was including all of them). This can be enabled by adding the following to your [clangd config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#standardlibrary):

```yaml
Index:
  StandardLibrary: Yes
```

In clangd 16, this feature will be enabled by default.